# Is "Kimi ga Aruji de Shitsuji ga Ore de" based on an alternative setting of "Majikoi"?

Tags: majikoi, kimiaru

So, I just finished watching [Kima ga Aruji de Shitsuji ga Ore de](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3229/Kimi_ga_Aruji_de_Shitsuji_ga_Ore_de). I watched this because it said "*Alternate Setting: [Majikoi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/10213/Maji_de_Watashi_ni_Koi_Shinasai)*".

It was a good anime and all, but, my question is how do these anime relate? All I've managed to find is that they were developed and published by Minato Soft.

Comment: Apparently - and I have no knowledge of these things beyond what I just looked up on VNDB - the character "Kuki Ageha" is present in both. Perhaps other characters are as well. The [relation graph](https://vndb.org/v1143/rg) on VNDB may prove informative.

Comment: @senshin having read both novels, there is not much more to say than that. They're clearly in the same universe and a couple characters are shared, but the stories are basically completely unrelated.

Comment: @LoganM I found an interesting statement on [Majikoi's Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9C%9F%E5%89%A3%E3%81%A7%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AB%E6%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%84!#.E4.BD.9C.E4.B8.AD.E8.A8.AD.E5.AE.9A). Apart from same universe and Kuki's family, it is also mentioned that *Majikoi* (or *Majikoi S*?) is 2 years after *Kimiaru*. If that's the case, then I think it can be said that it's indeed an alternative setting. However, I can't say much because I don't touch the series at all.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Personally I wouldn't use the term "alternate setting" even though MAL does. That to me seems to cover cases like [Futakoi](https://myanimelist.net/anime/125/Futakoi) and [Futakoi Alternative](https://myanimelist.net/anime/126/Futakoi_Alternative) or [Muv-Luv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muv-Luv) Extra and Unlimited.  I'd say this is more a case of "same setting" or at least "same universe". To me MAL's use of the terms is a bit unintuitive but maybe others don't find it confusing. In any case I'll write an answer in the next couple days if no one else does first.